# Shell script giving seemingly incorrect exit information

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

When I run this script with a folder as a parameter I get this error:

> lab9.sh: 1: eval: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

But how can this be? My line 1 has no open parenthesis. I thought the problem was my shebang but as you can see it's in perfect condition. Everything else in my script appears to be in order.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
firstPart='tar -cvf n00866097_Backup('
date='`date +%Y-%m-%d`'
lastPart=').tgz $file'
zippedFile=$firstPart$date$lastPart

eval $zippedFile

pscp -pw password $zippedFile user@192.168.100.80:[test]/
```

Comment: For the sake of debugging, add `echo ${zippedFile}` before your `eval`.

Comment: Ok. This is the result: tar -cvf n00866097_Backup(`date +%Y-%m-%d`).tgz $file
lab9.sh: 1: eval: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: wrong title:not  the shell made an error but you made it

Comment: Looks like `date` is your problem.

Comment: See [BASH FAQ 50 - I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F050.I.27m_trying_to_put_a_command_in_a_variable.2C_but_the_complex_cases_always_fail.21) and Avoid `eval`, see: [**BashFAQ #48: Eval command and security issues**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) and [**Is it always safe to use eval echo**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332579/is-it-always-safe-to-use-eval-echo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the filename containing `()` literals. And you could use `$()` to execute your `date` command. And don't mix up the `zipFile` with the command to create it, or your `pscp` won't work. Like,

```
file="$1"
zippedFile="n00866097_Backup($(date +%Y-%m-%d)).tgz"
cmd="tar -cvf \"$zippedFile\" \"$file\""
eval "$cmd"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `eval` or variables aside from `$date`:

```
date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
tar -cvf n00866097_Backup\(${date}\).tgz $1

pscp -pw password \
   tar -cvf n00866097_Backup\(${date}\).tgz $1 \
      user@192.168.100.80:[test]/
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course the error message of the shell is correct. In your script the shell is invoked two times. At first it is invoked when the script is started by running something like `./lab9.sh`. During the execution of this script the start of another shell is triggered by `eval` when exectuting

```
eval $zippedFile
```

In this context this newly started shell should execute the statement

```
tar -cvf n00866097_Backup(`date +%Y-%m-%d`).tgz
```

For this new shell this statement is the first one, so it's line number is 1. But `(` and `)`  have a special meaning for the shell it is syntactically wrong to place them here and so an error is raised. If you want them as part of the filename you have to escape them. But check the other answers, it is not a good idea to use `eval` here at all.